# How to drain a AA battery (9V at 2A)

Tags: power, batteries, dc-dc-converter, boost, converter

I want to know if it is possible to draw 9V and 2A from a normal alkaline AA battery using a boost converter? And if not so, why is it possible then to drain batteries quicker?

Comment: No. At 100% efficiency that would mean 12A at 1.5V. In practice, more than 12A. What do you *really* want to do?

Comment: I want to charge a power bank faster. @BrianDrummond

Comment: Let me get this straight, you're going to charge a power bank with batteries? What? Really?

Comment: A power bank will charge at the current that it decides is needed **or less**. To charge it at the fastest rate, apply the highest voltage it will take at the input using a supply that can deliver the current that the powerbank needs (this will be written near the input, like: 9V, 2 A). Charging a power bank using AA cells is **silly** as there is not so much energy in an AA cell. More practical would be a high power Lipo battery pack or a car battery. **Normal** people just charge their powerbank from the mains using a power adapter.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Don’t stop the magic

Comment: Am I right if I say that you will be able to charge a battery of 4000mAh to 50% with this 1.5V AA battery? If the AA battery gives 2000mAh? @BrianDrummond

Comment: @WihandeBeer - no, you are mistaken.  You need to learn about the difference between `current` and `power` which is the product of current and voltage.  The time integrals in milliamp hours can similar not be directly compared, until you multiply by the effective voltages to calculate energy stored.   So for example, an 1800 mAH NiMH "AA" stores only about a third as much energy as an 1800 mAH lithium cell, as the latter has about three times the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

\$ P_{out} = 9V×2A = 18W\$

Let's assume you're stepping it up with an efficiency of \$80\%\$

\$P_{in}=\frac{18W}{0.8}=22.5W\$

I will assume the terminal voltage for an AA battery is \$1.5V\$

The current required to deliver \$22.5W\$ with \$1.5V\$ is \$\frac{22.5W}{1.5V}=15A\$

Before we continue, let's just stop for a second and think about this. If you got an AA battery with these parameters: \$1.5V\$, \$2000mAh\$, then you can hypothetically draw those \$15A\$ for \$\frac{2Ah}{15A}=8\$ minutes. Nice, well it's your batteries. Not my problem.

And just one other thing before we continue, this might be equally awful.

\$P=A^2×R\$

Let's say  that the internal resistance of the battery is \$50mΩ\$, I don't think it's super unrealistic. FYI I'm not a battery guy. Either way, let's continue. Then the power wasted in the form of heat inside of the battery will be \$15^2A×0.05Ω=11.25W\$

And as far as I remember, the short-circuit current of a typical AA battery is around \$6A\$.

If you want to keep going with this idea, then you will at least need \$4\$ batteries in parallel, that way they will be able to supply the massive \$15A\$. The power lost in the form of heat in each of the batteries will be lowered by a factor of \$4^2=16\$ because the current will be a fourth in each of the batteries compared to before, and the power was proportional \$A^2\$ if you remember.

### TLDR; 4 batteries might work for a whopping  32 minutes

Also... this feels like a major [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now when I think about it.

Comment: @WihandeBeer I do **not** recommend doing it.

Comment: And note that the above calculation is being very optimistic, when you discharge AA alkaline cells in 32 minutes, they only deliver around 1000 mAh (source: dataheet of Duracell AA cells or any other manufacturer). I agree with Harry: **just don't**

Comment: I'm also saying that the voltage at the terminals of the battery has nothing to do with the current being drawn × internal resistance. Very sloppy, so you should add **much** more current being drawn out of the  batteries, because the voltage across the "1.5V" terminals won't be 1.5V any longer => more current => less volt => aaaaaah => AAAAAH! => EVERYTHING IS BURNING!

Comment: Am I right if I say that you will be able to charge a battery of 4000mAh to 50% with this 1.5V AA battery? If the AA battery gives 2000mAh?  
@HarrySvensson

Comment: @WihandeBeer **Don't even try it.**  I won't answer that.